# Crystal Reports Printing

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a winform billing application which has crystal report to print invoice.
I have set Crystal report page size as A4 in Crystal reports page setup. If i select A5 in printer settings does that output from crystal report as A4 become A5? I mean all contents of A4 becomes shrink to A5?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however, I think output depend on printer settings, as like if you can scale image via printer settings and it's must you can shrink them as well. [Check example for word](http://blog.prominenthosting.com/2009/02/10/how-to-print-one-a4-page-as-two-a5-pages-in-microsoft-word/)

But in general when I print SQL reports using pre-settings[hard coded] then its output follow the pre-settings value and not shrink according to the page.

[Please take a look and test it](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-57979)

I recommend you for test your settings and compare outputs because all printers may not include all advanced features.